# installing vmware ova on amazon aws

Tags: vmware, amazon-ec2

I am trying to import a vmware ova on amazon aws but experiencing issues.  After importing (or my attempt to import), I can no longer access the server via SSH even though the amazon AWS console shows the server as running.  I have tried restarting the server a few times. Any other steps that could fix this?